# How do I wrap a JavaScript object around HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the JavaScript that returns a `span` element with the `buttonClass` class:

```
$(this).find('span.buttonClass').sort()
```

I would like to wrap the returned JavaScript element with HTML tags like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="buttonClass"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I realize that I need to create the `tr` and `td` elements and then set `tr`'s child to be `td`, but how do I set `span` to be the child of `td`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var tr = document.createElement("TR");
var td = document.createElement("TD");
tr.appendChild(td);
```

But it won't let me do:

```
td.appendChild($(this).find('span.buttonClass').sort())
```

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Since you’re using jQuery, take a look at https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the element like the example below and call the [`.wrap`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method to add elements wrapping it.

```
$('span.buttonClass').wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```

Your previous attempt would not work because you tried to append a `jQuery` object to the `td`. So it would have worked if you tried the example below. `.get(0)` returns the first element in the `jQuery` object which would be `<span class="buttonClass"></span>` and that is a node valid to append.

```
td.appendChild($('span.buttonClass').get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementTarget = document.querySelector('body');

let newTags = [];

    newTags += '<tr><td><span class="buttonClass"></span></td></tr>';

    elementTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newTags);
```